# undefined method on decorated instance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, draper

Here is a decorator

app/decorators/campaign_decorator.rb

```
class CampaignDecorator < Draper::Decorator
  delegate_all Campaign::Campaign

  def created_at
    helpers.content_tag :span, class: 'time' do
      object.created_at.strftime("%a %m/%d/%y")
    end
  end

  def custom_method
    'hello there!'
  end
end
```

When I call `CampaignDecorator.custom_method` it doesn't find the method. Also `CampaignDecorator.first.created_at` returns unformated date.

Can anyone please tell what am I missing?

Comment: I don't know Draper but one sure thing is that your `custom_method` is defined as instance method but you call it on the class level (without any instance of CampaignDecorator).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is not how you use the Draper Decorator.

First things first:

- `CampaignDecorator.custom_method` tries to find a class method called `custom_method` in the CampaignDecorator class. Which is definitely NOT what you want.
- `CampaignDecorator.first.created_at` looks for objects of `CampaignDecorator` class and operates there ( where there are no records so `first` returns nil)

What you need to do is actually decorate your model. Check the [documentation](https://github.com/drapergem/draper#decorating-objects) for that.

You first need to add the functionality to your model:

```
class CampaignDecorator
  decorates :campaign
end
```

In short you could do

```
@campaign = Campaign.first.decorate

@campaigns = CampaignDecorator.decorate_collection(Campaign.all)

@campaigns = Campaign.scoped.decorate
```

Comment: I could not find any references mentioning to include decorator in AR model in the doc as well as on Railscasts(http://bit.ly/1zW1RqA). Anyway I tried your approach and getting `NameError: uninitialized constant Decorators` error if I try to include decorator in the model.

You mention that in `CampaignDecorator.first.created_at`, `first` would return nil. But that is not the case. This snippet returns original date not the formatted date.

Comment: `Campaign.first.decorate` works without needing `include Decorators::CampaignDecorator` in AR. I was using `CampaignDecorator.first` following railscast where decorator is being used to find record like `@user = UserDecorator.find(params[:id])`. Though `CampaignDecorator.first` return correct AR model, it doesn't decorate it.